# Is there a way to create custom normalised numpy array given a networkx graph containing nodes and weights in python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, graph-theory

I have a networkx undirected and weighted graph which has 'n' amount of nodes. I want to create a symmetric custom numpy matrix such that it is of shape n by n. I am trying to design a solution which is not dependant on the 'name' given to the node when created.

Each edge has a given weight.

Only three rules need to apply:

1. Diagonal of the matrix needs to equal to 1.
2. If two nodes in the graph are not connected then that position in the array is populated with 0. For eg if node 1 and node 2 are not connected then position(1,2) and position(2,1) equal to 0.
3. If two nodes are connected. For each of the nodes I need to calculate the sum of weight of all edges associated with that node and then apply `1/sqrt(w_1*w_2)`. For eg if nodes 1 and 3 are connected. Node 1 could be connected to 2 nodes in the graph, where the edge weight of those two connections are 0.6 and 0.4 respectively, therefore w_1=0.6+0.4. Node 3 could be connected to 3 nodes in the graph, where the edge weight is 0.5, 0.2, 0.1 respectively, w_2 =0.5+ 0.2+ 0.1. Hence position(1,3) and position(3,1) equal to 1/sqrt(1*0.8) = 1/sqrt(0.8).

I do realise that networkx has a built in normalized_laplacian_matrix functionality but from my understanding it does not build what I am looking for.

```
Example:
    FG=nx.Graph()
    FG.add_weighted_edges_from([('A','B',0.125),('A','C',0.75),('B','D',1.2),('C','D',0.375)])
```

Therefore this should yield the following matrix

```
   ([[1.        , 0.92872692, 1.00790526, 0.        ],
    [0.92872692, 1.        , 0.        , 0.69223218],
    [1.00790526, 0.        , 1.        , 0.75124823],
    [0.        , 0.69223218, 0.75124823, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: To clarify, in the third condition example, you say "node 1 could be connected to 2 other nodes in the graph".  Does this include node 3?  In other words, does node 1 have degree of  2 or 3?

Comment: Apologies, I see where you are coming from. It would have a degree of 2. Where one of the already established edges is between 1 and 3.

Comment: OK, thanks.  One more question.  In your example, from what I understand, A has total weight 0.125 + 0.75 = 0.875, and B has total weight 0.125 + 1.2 = 1.325, so edge A-B should have weight 1/sqrt(1.325 * 0.875) = 1/sqrt(1.159375) = 1/1.0767427733679016 = 0.928726920425144.  Not the 1/sqrt(2.2).  Where did 2.2 come from?

Comment: Yes you are right there, have amended accordingly.

Comment: The code should be blazingly fast now. See the first solution.

Comment: Does the answer work? Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Can you also upvote?  I have worked hard on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

```
import networkx as nx
FG=nx.Graph()
FG.add_weighted_edges_from([('A','B',0.125),('A','C',0.75),('B','D',1.2),('C','D',0.375)])

length = len(FG.nodes())
matrix = nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(FG)
new_matrix = np.zeros((length,length))
new_matrix = 1/np.sqrt(matrix.sum(axis=1)*matrix.sum(axis=0))
new_matrix[matrix==0] = 0
np.fill_diagonal(new_matrix,1)


new_matrix
matrix([[1.        , 0.92872692, 1.00790526, 0.        ],
        [0.92872692, 1.        , 0.        , 0.69223218],
        [1.00790526, 0.        , 1.        , 0.75124823],
        [0.        , 0.69223218, 0.75124823, 1.        ]])
```

### Solution 2

```
import networkx as nx
FG=nx.Graph()
FG.add_weighted_edges_from([('A','B',0.125),('A','C',0.75),('B','D',1.2),('C','D',0.375)])

length = len(FG.nodes())
matrix = nx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_matrix(FG)
new_matrix = np.zeros((length,length))

import numpy as np
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        if i == j:
            new_matrix[i,j] = 1
        elif matrix[i,j] == 0:
            new_matrix[i,j] = 0
        else:
            w_1 = matrix[:,i].sum()
            w_2 = matrix[j,:].sum()
            new_matrix[i,j] = 1/np.sqrt(w_1*w_2)
new_matrix
```

Comment: I do not think outputs the correct values. However after compiling I realised when the graph has many many nodes (1000), due to the nature of the nested for loops it can take a long time. As the application, is time sensitive, could there possible be another way to do this, doesnt have to use numpy

Comment: If you want speed, you have to rely on numpy. I will fix the outcome but looping might be inavoidable. Do you still want the solution with the loop?

Comment: If it is possible to design a solution without loops then that would be great! But if not then loops can work as long as the output is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I have solved it all with Matrixes for you! Enjoy it. It should be blazingly fast